# What user is shown on linux login screen?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, login

On `linux mint mate 17.2`, oracle-xe created a user `oracle` with `uid = 1001`, its password part in `/etc/shadow` is `*`, which means disable for login I guess.

But the user `oracle` still shows in the login screen.

I have tried to lock the user for login via `passwd -l oracle`, but it still shows on login screen.

**The questions are:**

- What kind of user is shown on login screen? Is that users with `uid >= 1000` ?
- How can I keep the user (*with uid >= 1000*), and stop it from shown in login screen?

Answer (score 1):

**Either** edit `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` (if AccountsService is not installed- older systems) and add `yourusername` to the `hidden-users` line e.g.:

```
[UserList]
hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess yourusername
```

**Or** (if AccountsService is enabled - e.g. ubutnu14.04) create a file named `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/yourusername` containing these lines:

```
[User]
SystemAccount=true
```

---

You can if check AccountsService is installed on Ubuntu with:

```
dpkg -l accountsservice
```

or for rpm based systems (e.g CentOS) with:

```
rpm -qa | grep glibc-static
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by indicating how OP could determine if UserAccounts is installed.

Comment: This don't work on my system. 1) There is no `/etc/lightdm/` dir on my system; 2) I have `accountsservice 0.6.35-0ubuntu7.2` installed, then added file `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/oracle`, and add the 2 lines, then reboot, but the user `oracle` still appear on login screen.